# Source files in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I am using two versions of ROS next to each other. To use one I have to source some environment variables for the specific version. I would like to create a script that does this. 
But if I create a script like below the variables are not set, they are probably set in a subshell. How can I source the files to the main terminal shell?

source.sh:

```
source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash;
source  ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash;
```

Here is how i am calling source.sh:

```
./source.sh
# This does not echo anything, but I expect it should
echo $ros_config
```

---

Update: By sourcing source.sh as suggested in the answer, I can now see the variables being set.

```
source ./source.sh
# This works now
echo $ros_config
```

Comment: What about sourcing `source.sh`? This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15968190/1983854

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**Execute Shell Script Using .  ./ (dot space dot slash)**

While executing the shell script using `“dot space dot slash”`, as shown below, it will execute the script in the current shell without forking a sub shell.

```
$ . ./setup.bash
```

In other words, this executes the commands specified in the `setup.bash` in the current shell, and prepares the environment for you.

Comment: `.` is an alias for `source` when delimited by space (like all bash commands). If you `source` you'll avoid common bugs associated with using `.` to mean the current directory, etc.

Comment: Note: `source` is an alias for `.` not the other way around.

Comment: This works fine for scripts in the current directory - but what do you do if the script is in /usr/local/bin? That's more convenient because then you don't have to cd to the directory where your script is located.

Answer (score 13):

Use dot notation to source in the script file in the ***current*** shell i.e. **without creating a sub-shell**:

```
. /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash
. ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash
```

Comment: If I use ./source.sh it does not work. source source.sh does work!

Comment: SInce you're providing full path to setup.sh here therefore `./` is not needed since `./` means current dir.

Comment: "`./source.sh`" executes the script (in its own shell). "`. ./source.sh`" (or "`source ./source.sh`", or "`source source.sh`") will apply the script contents to the current shell environment.