# `source ~/.bash_profile` do not works inside a bash script

Tags: bash, dot-source

This is a script that move a bash file into homepage and load it with source command.

```
# update.sh
#!/bin/bash
cp -f $PWD/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It does not work! It update file with `cp -f $PWD/bash_profile ~/.bash_profile`.

Inside `~/.bash_profile` there is a new PS1 definition. File is updated but no changes happened until new window is opened. I need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` after script execution ...

Is it possibile to run `source` command inside bash script?

Comment: You need to source the bash script if you want it to update your current shell.

Comment: It's possible, but useless for the same reason you are using `source` inside the script instead of executing `.bash_profile`.

Comment: The shebang must be the first line in the file.

Comment: Not a new answer, but some clarification. When you `echo "PS1=${PS1}" after `source ~/.bash_profile`, you will see it is changed. The changes get lost, when your script `update.sh` is finished. You can use `source` to keep the changes valid in your current shell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From MangeshBiradar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011245/source-files-in-a-bash-script):

Execute Shell Script Using `. ./` (dot space dot slash)

While executing the shell script using “dot space dot slash”, as shown below, it will execute the script in the current shell without forking a sub shell.

`$ . ./setup.bash`

In other words, this executes the commands specified in the setup.bash in the current shell, and prepares the environment for you.

Comment: sorry still not able to execute source ~/.bash_profile from within bash script

Comment: This was the only solution that works for me. Even starting a new shell (executing: `bash`) after I sourced the file didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear to me.. this solution is meant to go in .bash_profile? So the command in .bash_profile would be `source ". ~/script.sh"`? This does not seem to work. An applied example would be nice

Answer (score 3):

The bash script runs in its own instance of the shell.   When the shell exits, all environment variables of that new shell (including your `PS1`) are forgotten.  Note: this is a security consideration -- if a shell could change the environment of it's caller, it could very easily do some serious damage to that user by aliasing various commonly used commands.

If you run `source update.sh` though, it will run the commands as if the user typed them in on their own.   (or you could do as @JonathanMay suggested using the `.`, which does the same thing).