# ROS launchfile does not work in bash file

Tags: bash, ros

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/AFROS/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
roslaunch /opt/ros/melodic/launchfile.launch
```

I have this as my bash file that I would like to use to execute a launch file. I am able to launch the launchfile using

```
 roslaunch launchfile.launch
```

just fine, but if I use my bash file then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ros_core/connection_commander_node]: ros_core
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [ros_core/state_machine_commander_node]: ros_core
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011245/source-files-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Could you please share the content of launchfile.launch?

Comment: `roslaunch /opt/ros/melodic/launchfile.launch` and `roslaunch launchfile.launch` are not equivalent. Also the launch file should not be in `/opt/ros/melodic/` but in `/opt/ros/melodic/share/some_package/launch/` if it is a installed package. If you made the launch file yourself then you should put it in your workspace, otherwise you will lose it next time you update ROS. As noted, post the launch file you are launching. Also what directory are you in when you run the command `roslaunch launchfile.launch`. Add the output of `pwd` from the terminal where you ran roslaunch to the question.