# How do I make aliases work across all the shells?

Tags: bash, shell, aliases

I have been trying to make aliases work in bash shell. Now, let's say I do 
alias yum='yum -v' in my shell. It works when I run the run the command from CLI. But when I run a script it doesn't have any effect. How can I make the aliases work across the shell?

Comment: You can make the script source your `~/.bashrc` or any file containing these aliases.

Comment: Tried it, not working!

Comment: It should. See [using alias in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968053/using-alias-in-shell-script)

Comment: @fredtantini Alias expansion is disabled by default in non-interactive shells.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I didn't know that. When running a script with `. /home/fti/.bash_aliases`\n `ll` in ksh, my `ll` bash alias was executed…

Comment: Well, it's not really a `bash` alias, since you source the file in `ksh`.

Answer (score 2):

In bash, you can export functions, so if you do:

```
yum() { command yum -v "$@"; }
export -f yum
```

Then the 'alias' for yum will persist in subshells.  Note that functions are almost always preferred to aliases, and (from the bash man page) "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.".  I believe the initial clause 'For almost every purpose' is merely hyberbole and that 'almost' can be safely omitted.

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash` manpage:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of
>   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

As a result, you need to do the following inside your script.:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

You will also need to source your file with aliases (`.bashrc`,`.bash_profile`,`.bash_login` etc).

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source /path/to/alias/file
```

Please note that using `alias` inside your shell script will make it less portable as it will break when ran on environment that **do not** have your aliases.