# Set expand_alias when shopt not available?

Tags: shell, alias, ash

I'm trying to use an alias in a shell script I'm writing, but it is not working.

The alias:

```
alias ts="awk '{ print strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]\"), \$0 }'"
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
./copyTask.sh: ts: not found
```

Sooping around on the internet, it seems that I need to enable the `expand_aliases` shell option, but I don't have `shopt` installed... Is there any way I can enable alias expansion without using `shopt` or creating another rootfs image?

I'm using the `ash` shell. And `awk` is BusyBox v1.25.0 `awk`.

NOTE: The alias is an easy way to prepend a timestamp to a commmand:

```
$ echo "foo" | ts
[2005-06-23 11:52:32] foo
```

EDIT: as some people are having trouble understanding what I mean, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30944630/2634349)  has an example.

Comment: @Ignacio, can you elaborate?

Comment: alias the command means then you need to add that in .bashrc file, not sure what you want to do?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer, I want to create a 'local' alias. That is, an alias that is valid only during the execution of my script. It seems that this does not work unless `expand_alias` is set...

Comment: If you don't have `shopt`, your shell isn't bash. That happens, in practice, as if code is called with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: ...though if your shell is a new enough bash, you might want to use the new `printf %()T` support for timestamp formatting *internal to the shell itself*.

Comment: (BTW, is this busybox's embedded ash, or an external one? Easy way to test is looking at whether your `sh` binary is either a symlink to, or has the same inode number as -- and thus is a hardlink to -- the busybox executable; if it is busybox ash, I might change the title to "Using aliases in a script with busybox sh").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use aliases in scripts. A function does the same job *better*.

```
ts() { gawk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' "$@"; }
```

- This works with any POSIX shell, including ones that don't support aliases at all.
- This works with noninteractive shells without needing to enable alias support explicitly.
- This can be extended in ways that aliases can't (you can put conditional logic inside functions; you can put arguments in non-tail positions in functions; etc).
- In bash, functions can be exported to the environment: `export -f ts` will make the `ts` command available to subprocesses (where the shell they run is also bash).

Comment: Works perfectly on my host machine. However, the script I'm writing is for an embedded system, which has `ash`as its shell, and uses `awk`... When I run `$ ts "foo"` the result is `awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token`

Comment: If `awk '{ print strftime("[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"), $0 }' foo` gives the same error, then the shell (which is, after all, the subject of this question) is doing everything right.

Comment: BTW, when you ask a question where this is in-scope, you might consider specifying the *specific* version of awk your embedded system uses. I wouldn't be surprised if it were `nawk` or Busybox `awk`, but either way, details matter.

Comment: The command works normally, even when aliased. The issue is that if I try to create the alias inside a script, the alias isn't recognized, which I suspect is due to the lack of alias expansion.

Comment: I'm using busybox `awk`. Thanks for the tip. Will update the description.

Comment: Please run with `sh -x  yourscript`, and provide the log line for the awk invocation it's attempting. (As an aside, I've confirmed that busybox `awk` *does* provide strftime -- whereas MacOS's `awk` does not, for example).

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/4cca2c1d2c518efea5d9d0c13e2f64d6, with logs of my own test (and the script I used, showing this shell function working perfectly with busybox 1.21.1).

Comment: @ Charles, [here's my test](https://gist.github.com/guildeol/8ba17f9822583a2b9bf7def1e7ea18d4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159176/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-guilherme-costa).