# bash alias using sudo returning command not found

Tags: bash, alias, sudo

I am trying to use the solution of using sudo on my existing aliases as covered in many existing answers already and i am so confused as to why it is not working

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

I keep all my aliases in `.bash_aliases`. Inside `.bash_aliases` I have this

```
function _test {
    echo 'test!'
}

alias test='_test'
```

I reload the .bashrc each time; `source .bashrc` but when I run `sudo test` I always get

> sudo: _test: command not found

The only strange thing that happens is that I get the following on reload and not on a new terminal

> dircolors: /home/MYHOME/.dircolors: No such file or directory

but i feel this is a red herring.

Comment: `sudo` runs in a clean-ish environment. You can't execute user shell functions like this. The only reason the alias works is because it's expanded before sudo is called.

Comment: I updated the question to match my actual issue, but perhaps your comment still stands

Comment: `alias sudo='sudo '` doesn't do anything interesting. Nor does your function alias; you could simply define `test() { echo 'test!'; }` in the first place, no alias needed.

Comment: @myol chepner's comment _does indeed_ stand. `sudo` uses `execve()` to directly invoke the executable that is to be its child process; that's an OS-level syscall. aliases are just an interactive shell construct; they don't work at any other layer, including noninteractive shell scripts (and it's bad form to rely on them at all; while whether they can be exported across a privilege boundary depends on the details of how `sudo` is configured and it's much better from a security perspective if they're disallowed, exported functions can _sometimes_ work through `sudo`, whereas aliases never will).

Comment: Anyhow -- I'd argue this isn't on-topic here at all; it's a end-user question, not a software-development-specific one. [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) are better suited.

Comment: @chepner It was a minimal reproduction, replace echo with a command that needs elevated user privileges. Regardless, if I simply use `test() {echo 'test!';}`, with sudo, nothing is output

Comment: @myol You cannot directly `sudo` a function, an alias or a builtin, only an executable file that is on your disk. The indirect way of doing this is through `sudo bash -c ...`. All this looks like an XY problem to me, though

Comment: BTW, `function funcname { ... }` is legacy ksh syntax. Bash is compatible with that aspect of ksh, but some other modern shells aren't; it's better to use POSIX sh function syntax -- `funcname() {` with no `function`. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete, particularly the entry in the 3rd table (the 1st one covers syntax with no legitimate use outside code golf; the 3rd one, things only to use given a specific reason to prefer them, is the relevant one).

Comment: Tangentially, [Why would I create an alias which creates a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239089/why-would-i-create-an-alias-which-creates-a-function) discusses a related antipattern which is somewhat relevant for this case, too.

Answer (score 1):

[As l0b0 says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66020369/14122), aliases *cannot* be used in this way in bash.

However, you *can* pass a function through (and really, there's basically never a good reason to use an alias instead of sticking to functions alone).

```
_test() {
    echo 'test!'
}

sudo_test() {
  sudo bash -c "$(declare -f _test)"'; _test "$@"' sudo_test "$@"
}
```

...will define a command `sudo_test` that runs the function `_test` via `sudo`. (If your real-world version of this function calls other functions or requires access to shell variables, add those other functions to the `declare -f` command line, and/or add a `declare -p` inside the same command substitution to generate a textual description of variables your function needs).

Answer (score 0):

To run an alias like `alias_name` it *must* be exactly the first word in the command, so `sudo alias_name` will never work. Ditto `'alias_name'`, `\alias_name` and other things which eventually expand to the alias name.