# Trying to run a function in the Bash shell gives unexpected results

Tags: bash, alias, soffice

I have been trying to batch convert a bunch of really old MS office files to odf formats for archival purposes, using libreoffice from the command line. For this purpose I first gather all the files in a single directory and then invoke the following command (for doc files) within said directory:

```
/path/to/soffice --headless --convert-to odt *doc
```

This works well, and the command results in all doc files within the directory being converted in one go. I want to however avoid having to always type out the path to `soffice` with the necessary parameters, so I added the following to my Bash profile:

```
alias libreconv='function _libreconv(){ /path/to/soffice --headless --convert-to "$1" "$2"; }; _libreconv'
```

However, when I now try to invoke the following:

```
libreconv odt *doc
```

this results in only the first doc file in the directory being converted, after which the the function exits and returns me to prompt... Maybe I am missing something obvious (I am a cli newb  after all), but I do not understand why invoking the function results in only the first file being converted versus all files when I run the `soffice` command directly.

Thanks in advance for any aid helping me understand what is going wrong here. :)

Comment: What's the point in using an alias for **defining** a function????

Comment: @user1934428 There are probably some vague reasons to do that in some scenarios, but in this case it's probably a cargo cult copy of a beginner antipattern. See the question I link to in my answer for some discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Because your function only accepts two parameters.

Probably don't hardcode the path to `soffice`; instead, make sure your `PATH` includes the directory where it's installed.

The alias is completely useless here anyway; see also [Why would I create an alias which creates a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239089/why-would-i-create-an-alias-which-creates-a-function)

If you wanted to create a function, try something like

```sh
libreconv () { soffice --headless --convert-to "$@"; }
```

The arguments `"$1"` and `"$2"` literally expand to the first two arguments.  The argument `"$@"` expands to all the arguments, with quoting preserved (this is important if you want to handle file names with spaces in them etc; you see many scripts which incorrectly use `"$*"` or `$@` without the quotes).

Tangentially, if `soffice` is in a weird place which you don't want in your `PATH`, add a symlink to it in a directory which *is* in your `PATH`. A common arrangement is to have `~/bin` and populate it with symlinks to odd binaries, including perhaps scripts of your own which are installed for development in a Git working directory somewhere.

A common incantation to have in your `.bash_profile` or similar is

```sh
if [[ -d ~/bin ]]; then
    case :$PATH: in
     *:~/bin:* | *:$HOME/bin:* ) ;;
     *) PATH=~/bin:$PATH;;
    esac
fi
```

With that, you can (create `~/bin` if it doesn't exist; `mkdir ~/bin`) and `ln -s /path/to/soffice ~/bin` to create a symlink to the real location.