# Bash alias to avoid retyping the same command again and again

Tags: bash, function

I use the

```
rename -vf s'///gi' *
```

command tons of times a day. I don't want to have to retype it every time.
So I came up with the idea of creating an alias that calls a function into which I pass my arguments and then it executes.

Here's the idea I came up with:

I'd like it to work that way:
alias(**ren** is the alias) arg01 arg02  - and hit "enter"
The execution occurs.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function rename() {

#   variables

StringToReplace=$1
ReplacementString=$2

#   cmd

rename -vf s'/"$1"/"$2"/gi' *

}
```

For example:

filename:
*Torrent911 Io Battle For Pandora 2022.mkv*

Two possibilities:
1 - I want to delete something

The cmd would be:
`ren "Torrent911 Io␣"` #here I put nothing, I want to delete this.

Desired output:
*Battle For Pandora 2022.mkv*
I already have a problem here. The file name doesn't change and the shell doesn't indicate that I've made an error.

2 - I want to replace with something else.
Let's say replace 911 with 988
The command would be:

```
ren "911" "988"
```

Same result.

I know the concept is good. Maybe the problem lies in the way it's written. I'll take any good ideas that might help.

Comment: Tangentially, [Why would I create an alias which creates a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239089/why-would-i-create-an-alias-which-creates-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comments reveal a fair amount of confusion here. You seem to have a script containing a function and an alias which refers to this function.

The simplest solution by far is to have a script called `ren` in a file in your `PATH` which has the correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and is marked executable with `chmod a+x`:

```
#!/bin/sh
rename -vf "s/$1/$2/gi" *
```

If you don't want it to operate on all files in the current directory, perhaps change it so that parameters $3, $4 etc refer to file names to operate on.

```
#!/bin/sh
from=$1
to=$2
shift
shift
rename -vf "s/$from/$to/gi" "$@"
```

The `shift`s remove `$1` and `$2` from `"$@"` so that it only contains arguments `$3`..`$#`.

If you want to embed this in a function instead, you can do that. This is something you might put in your `.bash_profile` or similar.

```
ren () {
   rename -vf "s/$1/$2/gi" *
}
```

(Again, of course, you can apply the `shift` logic here as well if you prefer. Anything you can put in a script can also be put in a function. In that case, you probably want to mark the variables `from` and `to` as `local`.)

If you *want* to have a script which defines a function, you can do that, of course, though it seems superfluous at this point. You obviously also have to call that function, not just define it.

```
#!/bin/sh
ren () {
   rename -vf "s/$1/$2/gi" *
}
ren "$@"
```

There is absolutely no reason to call the function something else and then have `alias ren=othername`; this is just needless obfuscation and a waste of memory and namespace.

Comment: Oh My God!!!
The solution is so simple...
I really got confused by bad logic! I have to go to work but I'll definitely be back for more clarification on the shift concept.

Thank you very much,
sincerely,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

The parameter expansions must be outside of the single quotes.

```
ren() {

  rename -vf s'/'"$1"'/'"$2"'/gi' *

}
```

Note that quotes don't define a string; they just escape all characters enclosed within them. Two quoted strings that are juxtaposed constitute a single string (or to be more precise, a single *word*.)

Comment: Of course, none of the characters in single quotes need to be quoted at all; this could be simplified to `"s/$1/$2/gi"` or even `s/"$1"/"$2"/gi`

Comment: @triplee @chepner

I changed my script like this:

`#!/bin/bash

function rename() {

# variables

StringToReplace=$1
ReplacementString=$2

# cmd

rename -vf s/"$1"/"$2"/gi *

}`

The filename is the same: Torrent911 Io Battle For Pandora 2022.mkv

Then I typed this:

`ren "911" "988"`

The shell returned this: -bash: ren: command not found

So I think I've got the wrong approach...
An alias that calls a function to which I want to pass parameters... Not sure...

Comment: Would it be easier to just turn the function into a command in my bash_profile?

Something with prompts for me to enter the parameters...
Ex:
typing **ren** - hit ENTER
Prompt 01 - String to replace?
Typing **911** (for example)
Prompt 02 - Replacement String?
Typing **988** - hit ENTER

And execution occurs.

Does anyone have a better idea, or else how can I do what I've described above?

Comment: You called your function `rename`, not `ren`. The variables are completely useless, as you end up refering to `"$1"` and `"$2"` in the body anyway. Also probably don't use the `function` keyword; it provides no value here. If this is a script then you should call your function too, or just embed the logic in the script itself without a function. The wildcard in your function will match all files in the current directory (for properly defensive coding probably change it to `./*`; or modify the logic to accept one or more file names to operate on).

Comment: Interactive prompts are a step in the wrong direction IMHO; you prevent yourself from using the shell's history, autocompletion, variable expansion, and other usability features, and make it harder to call your script from another script.

Comment: If your function is really named `rename` then calling `rename` from within the function will result in endless recursion. You want `command rename` but the vastly superior solution is to forget about the alias and simply call your function `ren`.